# Removing fields of parent class in ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model that inherits from another model (not abstract)
I have a ModelForm for the inherited model, but i dont want to display any of the fields from the base model.
What is the best way to accomplish this other than explicitly manually adding each field to the exclude list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally go with setting the include fields to those of the current class so you don't have to reference (potentially) another file to see the fields. Also allows the parent to be updated without affecting your form.

You could potentially examine the fields within the `__dict__` and see if they belong to a parent, but I honestly don't think it'd be worth it. In short, there is no easy way.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Meta.exclude](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form)

```
class ChildForm(BaseModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = Amodel
       exclude = ('parentfield1', 'parentfield2')
```

Comment: I mentioned, "...adding each field to the exclude list?"